# Getting forbidden (403.14) when not going to /index but just /

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

With ASP.NET MVC, I have code as below and the standard route definition.  When I navigate to mysite.com/ExtjsRun I get a 403.14 error but when I go to mysite.com/ExtjsRun/index I get the controller executed.

My question is how to get the route /ExtjsRun to default to my index method.

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using WebApp.Models;

    namespace WebApp.Controllers
    {
        public class ExtJsRunController : Controller
        {

            [MultiTenantControllerAllow("svcc,angu")]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var str = "/ExtjsRun/" + Tenant.Name;
                return Redirect(str);
            }

        }

    }
```

Routing:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            namespaces: new[] {"WebApp.Controllers"},
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: The URL pattern is `controller/action` and you are trying to access `mysite.com/ExtJsRun` which is not correct. Change the default controller in RouteConfig above to `ExtJsRun` if you want default redirection to `mysite.com/ExtJsRun/Index`

Comment: I'm not wanting the day can of controller to be a extjsrun.  I'm just not wanting to type /index at the end of the url.  I want mysite.com/extjsrun to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Routing code as below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            namespaces: new[] {"WebApp.Controllers"},
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ExtJsRun",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You are not set the default controller to `ExtJsRun` and action to `Index`. By your code, the iis server searches for the `Home` controller and `Index` Action in that controller, that's the reason for your access denial
Hope this helps